# If more than one column name contains the same string, how to perform analysis on each

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I am performing analysis on several dataframes. Some of them have variables with really similar names, for example:

```
d = {'id': [1, 2, 3], '1-abc': [13, 15, 27], '2-abc': [23, 36, 12]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

In this example, I have specific analysis I want to perform on the quantity columns. When there is more than one column containing 'abc' I want to perform the analysis on **both** 'abc' columns.

I have tried `df['ABC']= df.loc[:,['abc' in i for i in df.columns]]` but this doesn't work on the dataframes where there is more than 1 column containing 'abc'

Is there a way to create an *if-else* statement that performs like the psuedo-code below?

```
for col in df.columns:
        if df.columns contains > 1 col containing 'abc':
                *perform analysis on 'abc' columns*
        else:
                continue
```

Comment: `df.loc[:,['abc' in i for i in df.columns]]` _should_ work here.

Comment: @rafaelc hmm, you are correct. I believe that's actually very similar to what the `like` method of `filter` is doing.

Comment: @BeRT2me I prefer the `filter` option that you posted as well because it's very concise ;) But if for some reason that code above is not working, then maybe the `like` method will not work too (maybe there's a hidden character between the `a` and `b` in `'abc'`, for instance).

Comment: The code isn't work, and wouldn't work with the `filter` method either, because you can't assign multiple columns of output to a single column without modifying it in some way~

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit broad, but a better way to obtain a subset of columns is `df.filter()`. Then you could perform your analysis on each column of the filtered DataFrame.

```
ABC = df.filter(like='abc').columns

for col in ABC:
    ANALYZE_ME(df[col]) # Perform analysis on each column
```

---

You can also pack two columns into a list with something like:

```
df['ABC'] = df.filter(like='abc').apply(list, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   id  1-abc  2-abc       ABC
0   1     13     23  [13, 23]
1   2     15     36  [15, 36]
2   3     27     12  [27, 12]
```